# How to replace text that doesn't fit on one line with an ellipsis, without allowing horizontal scroller

Tags: css

In the case that text does not fit on one line, within view without scrolling, I am trying to cut the sentence off and replace the remaining words with an ellipsis. I have added the following css to accomplish this, however, after adding "white-space: nowrap", a scroller is added to the modal, which I do not want. How can I prevent the horizontal scroller from appearing?

The modal with the text I am attempting to accomplish this with is here:
[image]

The CSS I have so far is:

I also tried using overflow-x:hidden; but this did not work in getting rid of the horizontal scrollbar.

```css
.myText {
    padding-right: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="myText">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi consequuntur nesciunt magnam unde, cumque dolorum, laudantium cum molestias delectus ad natus voluptatem, obcaecati ullam voluptatum error perferendis cupiditate consequatur rerum!
</div>

<div class="myText">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi consequuntur nesciunt magnam unde, cumque dolorum, laudantium cum molestias delectus ad natus voluptatem, obcaecati ullam voluptatum error perferendis cupiditate consequatur rerum!
</div>

<div class="myText">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi consequuntur nesciunt magnam unde, cumque dolorum, laudantium cum molestias delectus ad natus voluptatem, obcaecati ullam voluptatum error perferendis cupiditate consequatur rerum!
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you need to give us more info(code). The CSS you provided works as you're intending it to. So i'm assuming something else is interfering.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give max-width as some value and not a 100% which would solve the problem.

```
  .myText {
    padding-right: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 125px; /*here*/
  }
```

If this dosen't solve the problem, provide the output of this solution in comments